# form an array with javascript and then send the array to php for submission to database

Tags: php, javascript, html, arrays

I am trying to form a javascript function from this form:

```
<form class="responseForm" action="javascript:parseResponse123<?php echo $id; ?>()" id="responseForm<?php echo $id; ?>"> 
<input name="hiddenField5<?php echo $id; ?>" id="hiddenField5<?php echo $id; ?>" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $id; ?>" />
<input name="hiddenField4<?php echo $id; ?>" type="hidden" id="hiddenField4<?php echo $id; ?>" value="<?php echo $qty; ?>" />

<font color="red"><?php echo $val; ?></font><br />
<?php
$i=1;
while($i<=$qty)
{
?>
Participant <?php echo $i; ?>:<input name="hiddenField2[]" id="hiddenField2" type="text" /><br />
<?php  $i++;
 }
 ?>
<input name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

the participant input field(hiddenfield2) can be anywhere from 1 or more of the field by same name and id.

I then have this code for submission to php page:

```
function parseResponse123<?php echo $id; ?> () 
{
var hiddenField2<?php echo $id; ?> = $("#hiddenField2<?php echo $id; ?>");
var hiddenField4<?php echo $id; ?> = $("#hiddenField4<?php echo $id; ?>");
var hiddenField5<?php echo $id; ?> = $("#hiddenField5<?php echo $id; ?>");
var hiddenField1<?php echo $id; ?> = $("#hiddenField1<?php echo $id; ?>");

var url = "insert.php";

    $.post(url,{  hiddenField2: $('[name="hiddenField2<?php echo $id; ?>[]"]').serialize(),hiddenField: hiddenField5<?php echo $id; ?>.val(), hiddenField1:hiddenField1<?php echo $id; ?>.val(), hiddenField4:hiddenField4<?php echo $id; ?>.val()  } , 
    function(data) {

    });
    setTimeout(function() {

    $.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    data:"getNews=true",
    success: function(r){
        $("#newsContent").html(r);

    },
    error: function(){
 alert($(".hiddenField2<?php echo $id; ?>").val());     
$("#error").text($(".hiddenField2<?php echo $id; ?>")).fadeIn(300)
    }
})


},200);
 }
```

please ignore all the echo id's that are in there, they are there more for future use than anything.  I need help forming the array for hiddenField2 using javascript, then submitting it to insert.php, then how to decode the array so that php can use a foreach loop.  any help with this?

Comment: Send it in JSON format

Comment: Scary code you need to look at jQuery Selectors & JSON

Answer (score 0):

You should look into the jQuery Serialize function:

http://api.jquery.com/serialize/

```
$.ajax({
type:"POST",
data: $("#form-id").serialize(),
success: function(r){
 // do something here after success
});
```

**edit: elaborated**

I did not test this but you could do something like this

```
<form class="responseForm" action=""> 
<input name="formData[id]" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $id; ?>" />
<input name="formData[qty]" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $qty; ?>" />

<font color="red"><?php echo $val; ?></font><br />
<?php
$i=1;
while($i<=$qty)
{
?>
Participant <?php echo $i; ?>:<input name="formData[participants][]" type="text" /><br />
<?php  $i++;
 }
 ?>
<input name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Use something this for the javascript

```
<script>
    $("form.responseForm").submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var formData = $(this).serialize();
        $.ajax({
            url : '/insert.php', // assuming from root of your domain dir 
            type:"POST",
            data: formData,
            success: function(response){
                $("#newsContent").html(response);
            },
            error: function(){

            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

and in your insert.php

```
<?php

    $formData = $_POST['formData']; // an array of the form
    foreach($formData['participants'] as $participant){
        // do something
    }
?>
```

Comment: so something like this?  it still isn't working though, any suggestions?

[code]function parseResponse123<?php echo $id; ?> () 
{
 

 $.ajax({
 type: "POST",
  url: insert.php,
   $("#responseForm<?php echo $id; ?>").serialize());
});[/code]

Comment: If you have firebug on firefox or use chrome, you should be able to see what the request params are through the browser inspector. Should show you what exactly is getting sent through in the request. 

Also, why are you echoing ids with PHP? Are you using multiple forms? If so, you could use just add a submit event function for each form matching a certain class, and then it will send in the context of that specific form that was submitted.

Comment: using the code you provided as a starting point, where would the url go at that I want it to submit too?  I am using the browser inspector, and it is saying that the resource isn't found?